# Visualisation in RMarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, visualization

Could anyone give me an advice or some articles how to visualize KPIs like most visited sections in a website, most read blogs, number of unique visits weekly and monthly, and similar graphs. I'm working with RMarkdown dashboard. Which packages would be best to use? I would be grateful for any tips and sources.

Comment: Lots of resources [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) and [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The librarys that I've been using are:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyquant)
library(tibbletime)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(scales)
library(timetk)
library(here)
library(tinytex)
```

The quantmod library is the best one to create interactive graphics.
Lastly, I recommend you to read the chapter 3 of this book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ "Data Visualisation"